# Evaluate $\int_0^1 \frac{P_3(t)}{\sqrt{1-k^2 P_3^2(t)}}dt$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, elliptic-integrals

We have the following integral:
$$\int_0^1 \frac{P_3(t)}{\sqrt{1-k^2 P_3^2(t)}}dt$$
where $P_3(t)$ is a third-degree polynomial with all coefficients different from zero.
Is it an elliptic integral?

And above all, do you know any approximations for this integral?

Comment: I'd be very surprised if the integral could be expressed in terms of elliptic integrals. Very few hyper-elliptic integrals reduce to elliptic ones, and even in the simplest special cases where this can be done, the evaluations can still be quite intricate.

Comment: Note that $k$ plays no role here, since it can be absorbed in $P_3$. Are you asking whether $k \mapsto \int \limits _0 ^1 \dots$ gives an elliptic integral?

Comment: @AlexM. Not only this. I am especially asking if anyone knows an approximation of an integral of this type or related to it.

Comment: Ok, let me make sure (for the benefit of future readers, too): you are not asking whether the integral in $t$ is elliptic (which is so in an obvious way), you are asking whether your expression as a function of $k$ is an elliptic integral. Do I understand it correctly?

Comment: @AlexM. No. At first I thought that, given the symmetry of the integral, this could be elliptical. I was wrong. However there is also another question in my post, that is, to give any approximations for this integral: $\int_0^1 \frac{P_3(t)}{\sqrt{1-k^2 P_3^2(t)}}dt$.

Comment: Can we assume that the denominator is bounded away from $0$? That is, if it exists $\varepsilon > 0$ such that $\varepsilon \le 1 - k^2 P_3 ^2 (t) \le 1$ for all $t \in [0,1]$?

Comment: I do not know what you have in mind to do. If you want, you can write an answer, so I understand what you mean. :)

Comment: @Mark, I think what AlexM. is asking: Does $1-k^2 P_3^2 (t)=0$ for $ t \in [0,1]$?